# chrome browser is too small on my tiny tablet

Tags: google-chrome, tablet

I'm using google chrome browser on a 7 inch windows 10 tablet, or at least i'm trying too. the tabs, address bar, menus etc are tiny. i can zoom the contents easily but it is hard to navigate. does anyone know how to address this? i'd happily use another browser, preferable chrome based like chromium?

Answer (score 0):

Is it just the Chrome browser or is it all “tabs, address bar, menus etc”? If the latter, try increasing your Display Size from Settings / Display and change the Size to 125% or such.

Comment: "i can zoom the contents easily but it is hard to navigate."